# Scroll Bar in QStackedWidget in qt

Tags: qt

I am using Qt Designer and I have a QStackedWidget. On one of the pages the data exceeds the size limit of the page. I added a Vertical Scroll Bar but it is not working when I run the application. Do I have to write any code for it. Please someone help with this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `QStackedWidget` into `QScrollArea`. In general, if you want something to be scrollable, you put it into `QScrollArea`.

Comment: If it's only needed on one of the pages, you'd have to put a `QScrollArea` in the `QStackedWidget`.

Comment: I tried putting the QStackedWidget into QScrollArea... 
This is what I am doing 

QScrollArea *area = new QScrollArea; 
area->setWidget(stackedWidget); 

When I run it is not even showing the StackedWidget.

Comment: Set `setWidgetResizable(true)`.

Comment: Still the same...I have dragged the scroll area itself for whichever page I require more space so that is doing the work as of now... Thank You all...

Comment: Well I have tried both the methods. If I have my stacked widget on scroll area it is not helping at all. I have to add scroll area to every page that I require and have to put all the items in a layout with the scroll area. I have a query here as to if I have around 100 pages where scroll area might be required is it advisable to go with this method? 
Thank You... :)

Comment: @user2548968, in order to make QStackedWidget inside of QScrollArea work you can try to play with size policies of QStackedWidget or its inner layout. (Also note that your code in your first comment of this answer is useless, you'd better use QtDesigner for that)

Comment: Yes I am doing it using QDesigner. Lets see I will try something tomorrow and if I get something I will post it here... Thanks :)

Comment: I had to put every page in a QScrollArea like here: https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/commit/0e1bd9b40dd0e20cd8f439cc4eaada9660a00cda

Just putting the QStackedWidget into a QScrollArea didn't do the trick for me.